# How can I get `stdout` back in a running cell of a reloaded Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, stdout, python-3.7

I run a Jupyter notebook.  One cell contains a control loop of a CPU/memory intensive FEniCS computations.  The loop uses `print(i)` as a progress indicator (where `i` is the iteration count).  As [there have been other notebooks running in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74864501/how-can-i-get-pid-of-a-running-jupyter-notebook), swapping happened and the frontend of the notebook has been reloaded. That left me with:

- the kernel process running (I can see it in the `htop` output),
- the kernel is busy (I requested to execute another cell and I am still waiting, the cell is marked `[*]`),
- the `stdio` output of the cell is frozen as it has been somewhen before the reloading (37%),
- the cell is marked as neither executed nor running (`[ ]`),
- the notebook favicon is "busy" (a hourglass),
- the kernel ignoring (?) interrupt requests - it does not stop when I click the stop button (but I am used to such behaviour when I use FEniCS).

From experience I know, that either:

- the cell is actually running, the state is there, and I can access it will be accessible after the execution is finished,
- the cell has hanged (e.g. kernel is deadlocked performing some kind of busy waiting or so, IDK).

I have interrupted the kernel (with either Jupyter notebook frontend or `kill -2` - I had tried both).  The cell was actually running and the control loop was at 98% (no data lost though).  But I still want to know **whether there is any way I can get access to `stdout` stream in cases like this** (without interrupting the execution unless it can be resumed exactly where it was interrupted).

Comment: why are you trying to run another cell while another cell is running? you can't do that. can you instead open 2 jupyter notebooks and run them separately ?

Comment: i think you should be using the multiprocessing, multithreading or async or a mix of these so you can do what you need to do and let python decide which cores or threads you need to use.

Comment: @anarchy I am not (trying to run another cell while another is running).  I "schedule" them to run serially either by "Run all" or more manually.  Running multiple notebooks is exactly what I do.  "Poor man's parallelism" I'd say.
I do not touch multithreading, but FEniCS does.  Jupyter does its multiprocessing, Ubuntu - multitasking, and the result is forced reloading of the notebook's frontend, thus lost `stdout` of the cell running in background.